# Accessing a value via key in json is throwing undefined

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, typescript

Hello I am facing a weird error, i have a below object

```js
    let dataFromUrl =  {
      "careerTrackId": 510,
       "country": [],
       "geography": [18],
       "ou2": [51549564],
       "ou3": [],
       "ou4": [],
       "ou5": [],
       "ou6": [],
       "ou7": [],
       "ou8": [],
       "region": []
    } 

console.log(dataFromUrl.geography.length);


// Here in this method iam using this dataFromUrl

   

     function getGeoUnitId(dataFromUrl) {
    console.log("dataFromUrl",dataFromUrl);
  console.log("dataFromUrl.geography",dataFromUrl.geography);
  console.log("dataFromUrl.ou2",dataFromUrl.ou2);
  console.log("dataFromUrl.careerTrackId",dataFromUrl.careerTrackId);
      let geoUnitId = "(" + dataFromUrl.geography + ")";
      let str2 = "geounitid IN " + geoUnitId;
      if (dataFromUrl.geography.length == 0) {
        str2 = "";
      }
      return str2;
    }
```

But when i am trying to use `dataFromUrl.geography.length` in my `nodejs` code, i get below error:

> [ 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined']

This code was running when my target was es5 bu as soon as i changed the target to es6 it's starting to break. Does any1 have any idea why this suddenly started happening.

Comment: Is there a little more code you can show on how you are accessing it? It seems like it should work to me.

Comment: iam doing the same in typescript-playground and its working for me.

Comment: I just tried your code and it is working fine. Are you sure you are not missing something in your original code ?

Comment: nope !! iam just putting the method in which iam using the property.

Comment: Try logging things in sequence, you might be overriding the variable, start with doing `const dataFromUrl = ....` instead of `let`. Then do:
`console.log('dataFromUrl: ', dataFromUrl);`
`console.log('dataFromUrl.geography: ', dataFromUrl.geography.length);`
`console.log('dataFromUrl.geography.length: ', dataFromUrl.geography.length);`
and see what it prints

Comment: did that, i can see the data in variable but when it comes to access its properties its goinf undefined

Comment: You are missing something. As others have said, the code you have shared is valid. You are leaving out some code that you have not shared that is mutating the object, or wherein you are mis-referencing the object. You have not shared enough information with us for us to debug the issue.

Comment: i swear only this much is the code

Comment: how are you calling getGeoUnitId?

Comment: Anyway, my suspicion is that dataFromUrl is being declared twice in two different scopes and unless you are explicitly passing it in, it's being read as an empty variable somehow. Try renaming the method argument variable to something else.

Answer (score 0):

After going through the comments, my possible guess is that you are calling the `getGeoUnitId()` without arguments and it's using the `getGeoUnitId` defined outside which you might have changed.

Try rename the arguments variable name

```
function getGeoUnitId(somethingOtherThan_dataFromUrl) {
```

Tip: If you are having a problem understanding the JS code, you should use the Chrome's (or any other browser) developer tools and add a debugger to see the flow of the code, how variables are being assigned values, where they are updated and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i was able to fix it, i still don't know why but this worked :
JSON.parse() did the trick.

```
let dataFromUrl =  {
      "careerTrackId": 510,
       "country": [],
       "geography": [18],
       "ou2": [51549564],
       "ou3": [],
       "ou4": [],
       "ou5": [],
       "ou6": [],
       "ou7": [],
       "ou8": [],
       "region": []
    } 


  function getGeoUnitId(dataFromUrl) {
    console.log("dataFromUrl",dataFromUrl);
  console.log("dataFromUrl.geography",dataFromUrl.geography);
  console.log("dataFromUrl.ou2",dataFromUrl.ou2);
  console.log("dataFromUrl.careerTrackId",dataFromUrl.careerTrackId);
      let geoUnitId = "(" + dataFromUrl.geography + ")";
      let str2 = "geounitid IN " + geoUnitId;
      if (dataFromUrl.geography.length == 0) {
        str2 = "";
      }
      return str2;
    }

 dataFromUrl = JSON.parse(dataFromUrl );
 console.log(dataFromUrl.geography.length); // this started giving me 1
```